# Squashed Sprite when turning horizontally

Tags: animation, gml, game-maker-studio-2

[Unsquashed Sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ7k8.png) [Squashed Sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUPPo.png)

My brother has issues with his sprite squashing whilst moving horizontally. The squashing is permanent after moving. I have found the line that causes the problem but cannot figure out what is causing this issue. When I remove this line the squashing stops however the sprite does not turn. He is following Shaun Spalding's Complete Platformer Tutorial and though I've watched it over I cannot find any issues with the actual code.

```html
/// @description Insert description here
// You can write your code in this editor

// get player input
key_left=keyboard_check(vk_left);
key_right=keyboard_check(vk_right);
key_jump=keyboard_check_pressed(vk_up);

// calculate movement
var move=key_right-key_left;

hsp=move*walksp;

vsp=vsp+grv;

if(place_meeting(x,y+1,o_wall)) and (key_jump)
{
    vsp=-7;
}

// horizontal collision
if (place_meeting(x+hsp,y,o_wall))
{
    while(!place_meeting(x+sign(hsp),y,o_wall))
    {
        x=x+sign(hsp);
    }
    hsp=0;
}
x=x+hsp;

// vertical collision
if (place_meeting(x,y+vsp,o_wall))
{
    while(!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),o_wall))
    {
        y=y+sign(vsp);
    }
    vsp=0;
}
y=y+vsp;

// animation



if(!place_meeting(x,y+1,o_wall))
{
    sprite_index=splayerA;
    image_speed=0;
    if (sign(vsp) > 0) image_index = 1; else image_index = 0;
}
else
{   
    image_speed=1;          
    if (hsp==0)
    {
        sprite_index=s_player;
    }
    else
    {
        sprite_index=splayerR;
    } 
}

if (hsp != 0) image_xscale = sign(hsp); //this line is wrong and causes the squishing
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause of this is that you've set the `image_xscale` to a different value before using the line:

```
 if (hsp != 0) image_xscale = sign(hsp);
```

For example, you may have set this in the Create Event to enlarge the sprite:

```
image_xscale = 2;
```

But that value is reset after setting `image_xscale` again, as that line will only return `-1` or `1` because of the Sign().

One quick solution is to apply the scale change to that line of code, like this:

```
if (hsp != 0) image_xscale = 2 * sign(hsp);
```

(Once again, presuming you've changed it's scale value somewhere else)

Though another solution is to enlarge the sprite itself in the sprite editor, so the scale doesn't have to be kept in mind everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue,(I used similar to Shaun Spaldings code too) but if you go into the resize sprite editor you can scale the image down and that solves the problem. Its the button that looks like full screen (4 arrows facing outwards to each corner) when looking at the sprite in the workspace. There must be some bug with Gamemaker when you scale an object down so much it cant handle it, so the solution is to change the sprite scale out of the room. Goodluck,
-DuckMan-